# How to detect if a previous redirect was invoked?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

Validating view-parameters in `preRenderView` event in the backing bean I observed that each event `<f:event>` is still fired even if any of the methods invoked a redirect using:

`FacesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);`

If in multiple events a redirect is invoked an illegal state error exception will be thrown.

To prevent this I would like to know if and how it is possible to generally detect wether a redirect was already invoked and either process the first or the last redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FacesContext#getRenderResponse()` to confirm if the process (or order) to proceed to the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase has been initiated. This checks whether `renderResponse()` method has been called by a component, signalling the runtime to transfer control to the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase. Generally at this point it's unsafe to attempt to do anything with the response stream.

Another route to the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase is the `FacesContext#responseComplete()` method. This however, does not directly trigger the response processing. Rather, it's the final flag to indicate to the runtime that `RENDER_RESPONSE` has been arrived at.

So, per the spec, `FacesContext#getResponseComplete()` is the ultimate check to verify the state of the response

> In some circumstances, it is possible that both renderResponse()and responseComplete()might have been called for the request. In this case, the JSF implementation must respect the 
>   responseComplete()call (if it was made) before checking to see if renderResponse()was called.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to remove this error. About: `Generally at this point it's unsafe to attempt to do anything with the response stream.` So I have no chance to stop redirect to first url to redirect to second url?