# JSF readonly inputText issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Readonly inputText doesn't validate if `required="true"` is set.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" id="townShipPanelGroup">
    <p:inputText value="#{AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.beneficiariesInfoDTO.residentAddress.township == null ? '' : AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.beneficiariesInfoDTO.residentAddress.township.name}" 
        style="width:250px;margin-left:-4px;" id="townShip" readonly="true">
            <f:validateLength maximum="36"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:commandLink immediate="true" oncomplete="selectTownShipDialog.show()" id="selectTownShipDialogLink" action="#{AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.loadTownshipList()}">  
    <h:graphicImage url="/images/search.png" style="height:30px;width:30px"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Are you sure, you can use == in value attribute?
Look at this [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4870557/1692632)

Comment: try with fix value and then tell us wich is the result

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is behaving as expected. For all intents and purposes, JSF doesn't evaluate a value that is designated as `readonly="true"` throughout the request lifecycle. The recommended way to get this done is to make the value readonly during the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase, where the view is being presented to the user. During any other phase, you want the JSF runtime to interpret the input field as writeable. For that purpose, you can use:

```
<p:inputText value="#{AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.beneficiariesInfoDTO.residentAddress.township == null ? '' : AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.beneficiariesInfoDTO.residentAddress.township.name}" 
        style="width:250px;margin-left:-4px;" id="townShip" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
            <f:validateLength maximum="36"/>
    </p:inputText>
```

This way, the `readonly` property is only true when the user is viewing the page. For all other phases, the JSF runtime will see the field as writeable and as a result, validation will be carried out on the field

References:

- [JSF Readonly input not validated](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1719997)
- [How to detect if a previous redirect was invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674965/how-to-detect-if-a-previous-redirect-was-invoked/18685794#18685794)
- [jsf (richfaces) readonly input text validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614706/jsf-richfaces-readonly-input-text-validation)

Comment: Since JSF2, `#{facesContext.renderResponse}` is not anymore guaranteed to work in all cases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639415/make-pcalendar-readonly/17639554#17639554

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje. If a malicious user edits the client-side markup to remove the readonly attribute, they could possibly supply a value. OP should envisage that as part of the "validation" that's referenced in the question

Comment: readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" onkeypress="return false;" is working fine