# Read only property makes it unable to update managed bean value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am submitting a form in prime faces with two text fields which are read only. I am setting value in them using JavaScript. But when I submit the form then in manage bean value of both text filed is `null`. If I however, remove read only, then it works fine. Please tell me the way out?

Comment: if you use `disabled` attribute of jsf, it prevents fields from being submitted. try disabling them using javascript/jquery.

Comment: I don't want to disable the text fields

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF readonly inputText issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693205/jsf-readonly-inputtext-issue)

Comment: The linked question will indeed tell you how exactly you will be able to retrieve the value of `readonly` input components. It is not only about validation. Validation is not performed because `readonly` is set to `true` there.

Comment: use hidden tag (h:inputHidden) to get values in manage bean.